# Help in chosing Mosfet

Tags: led, mosfet

we have a circuit using a DAC http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5593R.pdf so basically the DAC output voltage is from 0 to 5V

This DAC needs to finely control current in a LED (that needs from 8microamp to 15 miliamps in 1024 steps)...therefore the need for a Mosfet

Can anyone help us to find a suitable part ?

Adding three more details (important)
1. We will use an ADC for sensing
2. Vin = 5v
3. Controller  will be present on board

Comment: [**This answer**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/243369/3288) may help with MOSFET selection. If you drive the MOSFET with an opamp in a closed loop a wide range of MOSFETs should be suitable - as the opamp looks after ensuring Iout matches DAC out and the MOSFET just 'follows the opamps commands'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MOS part is not difficult, any MOSFET which can withstand the voltage and current will do but you have underestimated the problem. Just controlling the gate will yeild very unpredictable results and no regulation so this will be difficult.

Best option is op-amp and current feedback but if you want to keep it open loop and simple, an BJT instead of FET with suitable beta and base resistor will give you far more control.

BJT, slightly better than FET solution but still plenty of drift and no regulation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHMHNQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One possible opamp-solution, 12 V supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fluSjE.png)</sup>
5 V only equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcZJM4.png)</sup>

Comment: I am planing on having also a ADC in the same board for some feedback

Comment: You can feedback the current from SENSE to your ADC and do the regulation in software. Opamps are 0.05 € each though and will solve your problem once and for all. There are even special LED drivers that can take analog or I2C input to drive your LED. 20 mA is assumed in both schematics. Adjust if needed.

Comment: One more problem...my voltage is only +5V

Comment: For 5v operation, use @winny's second circuit, use a 5 volt rail-to-rail op-amp, loose the top resistor (R2), adjust the bottom (current-sense) resistor (R1) accordingly. If you need precise control, as winny implied, the first circuit may not be good enough. It cetainly won't do a 10-bit DAC justice.

Comment: Oh, and be sure to use a logic-level MosFET.

Comment: I can draw a new circuit for 5 V operation.

Comment: Ok last edit....we will use a minimum of 12 bit ADC/DAC (preferably 14). Will the second circuit work at those resolutions ? Yes please winny draw the circuit for 5v. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JohanB. Already done. See above.

Comment: This is a good circuit. I will chose it as answer. Thx you. One last specification, is there a better Mosfet to chose in order to control 8 micoamps to 20ma with enough 12-14 bit precision ? I am thinking to use this http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/EN6559-D.PDF

Comment: @JohanB. It does not matter which MOSFET you use at all, provided that it: has sufficiently low RdsON so that you don't drop more voltage over it than you can afford before running out of headroom and low Vgs so that you again don't run out of 5 V headroom. Choose an opamp which is rail-to-rail on BOTH input and output to save troubles later on.